# Text Cursor is too big and prevents fitting of the text area

Tags: adobe-illustrator, page-layout, typesetting

I am trying to fit a text box to the text inside the box, but the cursor and height of the selection of the text is too tall. Whenever I try to fit the text box, the text disappears.

[image]

This font is called Replica (Light).

[I found this help page on the Adobe community](https://community.adobe.com/t5/photoshop-ecosystem-discussions/text-cursor-too-big-type-not-lining-up-like-it-should/td-p/9872511) where the culprit was the baseline shift - which is not the issue in my situation.

[image]

*Illustrator 26.0.3*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Type is set to **superscript**. Select the type and toggle that setting.

[image]

Comment: *sigh* ok, thanks

Comment: .. been there `:)`

Comment: Thanks. I removed the superscript toggle but I still have a hard time with the leading of this text block... https://imgur.com/a/enUnRO3

Comment: @MicroMachine It *looks* like you've got the Area Type box set to **Justify Vertically**. Those options aren't available in my preferred AI version. So I don't *really* know where they are located. Maybe the menu.... `Type > Area Tye Options`

Comment: Yup.... `Type > Area Type Options...` : https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/align-text.html#:~:text=Choose%20Type%20%3E%20Area%20Type%20Options,the%20top%20of%20the%20frame.

Comment: I don't have Illustrator - but it looks like the type is set to 26 px but the leading is set to 14 px. Wouldn't that cause a problem?

Comment: @JeffK That would cause the type to overlap itself on 2 lines... which *could* absolutely be an issue. But it's not the issue here.